# url_for and route defaults in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I have a rails route set up like:

```
match ':controller/:id/:action'
# match 'teams/:id' => "teams#show" # doesn't have any additional effect, which makes sense to me
resources :teams, :only => [:index, :show]
```

That way I can say `/teams/cleveland-indians` and it will call `teams#show` with `:id => 'cleveland-indians'`. Works great. My issue is that `url_for` doesn't quite do what I want. In my views/teams/index view, I get this behavior:

```
url_for(:id => "cleveland-indians") # => /teams/cleveland-indians/index
url_for(:id => "cleveland-indians", :action => :show) # => /teams/cleveland-indians/show
```

Of course that second one behaves the way I want, but I'd like to get rid of the unnecessary `/show` at the end. I don't know much about how these helpers work, but I'd have guessed it would know that `show` was the default action for a GET with a specified id, same as the routing engine does. Anyway, what's the best way for me to take care of this? Or am I just doing it all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'resources' line should already provide you with the routes you probably want so you can just remove first 'match' line.

Note that you can also use 'teams_path', 'team_path("cleveland-indians")' instead of 'url_for'.

Comment: Removing the resources line stops links to my non-RESTful actions from working, e.g. `link_to(name, :action => 'other_action')` gives me an error. Is the problem really that I'm mixing RESTful resources with non-restful routes?

Comment: then you can either use resource's collection/member actions: `resources :posts do get :other_action, :on => collection end` or move your 'match' line below 'resources' in routes file